# Splitting String while copying information

Tags: r, string, split, delimiter

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to split the code string so it ends up with just one chacter in the code column with new rows for each one, but the columns around it are the same. Like this for the first one.

[image]

Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: You could either split your `code` variable into single character variables that you add to your dataframe and then use one of the `reshape` or `reshape2` functions to "melt" your rows. Or, you could make a loop where you iterate over the `code` string and for each character, append a row to a distinct dataframe with whichever variables you wish to keep.

Comment: Don't post images of data. It's useless. Post the actual data or a subset, e.g., using `dput(head(mydata))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the `cSplit` function from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "code", sep = "", direction = "long", stripWhite = FALSE)
#     event_id code staff_id
#  1:   124456    .     2222
#  2:   124456    C     2222
#  3:   124456    C     2222
#  4:   124456    D     2222
#  5:   124456    S     2222
#  6:   124456    S     2222
#  7:   123849    .     2222
#  8:   123849    S     2222
#  9:   123849    S     2222
# 10:   123849    B     2222
# 11:   123849    B     2222
# 12:   123849    S     2222
# 13:   234829    .     2343
# 14:   234829    S     2343
# 15:   234829    S     2343
# 16:   234829    B     2343
# 17:   234829    B     2343
```

---

This assumes we are starting with data like:

```
df <- data.frame(event_id = c(124456, 123849, 234829),
                 code = c(".CCDSS", ".SSBBS", ".SSBB"),
                 staff_id = c(2222, 2222, 2343))
```

Comment: Now you know why I asked :-) Very useful, this function!

Comment: That is a useful function, thank you! I will add that into my code, I had a workaround where I split code into 20 separate columns and then created 20 data frames, with event_id, codecolumn 1 (through 20), staff_id and then rbinded them together and removed blanks. Pretty much the least good looking code possible but it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be try:

(df is your data set)

```
event_id <- c(124456,123849)
code <- c(".CCDSS",".SSBBS")
staff_id <- c(2222,2222)
df <- data.frame(event_id,code,staff_id)

A<-apply(df,1,function(x)data.frame(event_id=x[[1]],code=unlist(strsplit(x[[2]],"")),staff_id=x[[3]]))
do.call(rbind,A)
```